# jQuery .val('xxx') not setting value, but .attr('value', 'xxx') is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which is populated with javascript, fetching data via ajax. I have a `<tr>` template which I clone and set the values within to the data retrieved via the ajax request. I'm using Twitter bootstrap's [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers), so that users can click on a cell, which pops the popover with an input/select etc prompting the user to change the cell value. The problem occurs when I am setting the value of those inputs. When I am building each row, I set the value of the input in the popover template with `.val('xxx')`, but when I log it/click the cell and view the popover, nothing is changed; conversely, if I set it with `.attr('value', 'xxx')`, it works just fine.. why would `.val('xxx')` not work?

Here's what the meat of it looks like..

**Row template:**

```
    ....
    <td>
        <div class="last-name popover-toggle">
            <span class="vlabel">----</span>

            <div class="popout">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""/>
                <div class="popout-button-container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small cancel-field">Cancel</button>
                    <button data-url="{{ url('edit_lead.json') }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small save-field">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    ....
```

**Setting input value:**

```
...
if (data['last_name']) {
    $nRow.find('.last-name input[name=last_name]').val(data['last_name']);//.attr('value', data['last_name']);
    $nRow.find('.last-name .vlabel').text(data['last_name']);
}
registerPopover($nRow.find('.last-name'), 'Last Name');
....
```

**Register popover:**

```
function registerPopover(el, title) {
    var options = {
        animation: false,
        content: el.find('.popout').html(),
        html: true,
        trigger: 'manual'
    };
    if (typeof(title) != 'undefined') {
        options['title'] = title;
    }
    el.popover(options);
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's happening, can you reproduce the problem on a live demo?

Comment: I think `$nRow.find('.last-name')` will return a set of elements. Have you tried using `$nRow.find('.last-name').each(function() { /* ... */ });`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I logged the result of `$nRow.find('.last-name input[name=last_name]')`, it is just one element, thought of that too :/

Comment: By the way, have you tried it on another browser? I've seen some cases where `val()` works OK (like Chrome), but on Firefox/IE/Safari it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your actual problem, question is not very obvious to me but there is a difference between `attr` and `val`. The `attr` method sets/change the `attribute` of an input/element in the source and you may see it using browser's inspection tool, on the other hand, `val` method sets/update the rendered property which is in the memory but it doesn't effect the original `source/HTML` in the browser's source code. For example, if you do something like this

**HTML:**

```
<input type = "text" name="txt" id = "txt" value = "Hello!" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('#txt').val('World!').clone().insertAfter($('#txt'));
```

And check the source code, then you'll see there is two `input` elements and both have value attribute `Hello!` but on the screen both have `world!`. [Check this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Comment: I think you may have solved it, to grab the contents of the popover, in registerPopover(..) I set the `content` option in the popover() method, which uses `element.find('.popout').html()`, are you saying that since I am only setting value of the `value` property and not the attribute, when .html() is called to retrieve the html for the popover, that information is lost?

Comment: I just gave you the idea difference of both methods and I didn't see you used `html` in your code and was bit confused about the question.